# Unity add property animation dependence

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add animation properties, I want to make sure that on one frame I have the box collider turned on and on the next frame it is turned off, but when I add a key, the properties are dependent and both are either turned on or off, what should I do?

I tried to delete properties or other box colliders, but at first a new property was added when I turned the collider on and off, and then when I completely deleted the property and added it, this property disappeared, but independent properties for animation were still not created

Comment: Did you try to set different key event directly on Animation Clip and try to disable/enable BoxCollider component?

Comment: how to put different keys? I mean, I just already have a ready-made box collider and it just needs to be turned on and off on different animation frames.

Comment: Please see this video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8. Typically, open your animation clip in animation inspector, press record, and switch to the key frame that you want to turned On/Off the box collider. After that, just action it. The action will be recored in animation clip of your operation.